# Json parse to Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

I have used retrofit once to turn parse json into java classes but now I have this json data which is a list of movies and the problem when I use the site jsonschema2pojo it creates classes with movie names but the problem is the movies keep changing everyweek is there someway to do it . I added some image down here from jsonviewer.stack so you can see what I mean

[image]

[image]

I dont need a class name Sing or Fences because next week there are other movies hope you guys understand what I mean

Comment: Why you are creating node of a movies name? You need multiple json object inside your 'movies' array and each object contains movie name as string. You have to change your json response structure.

Comment: @PravinD I cant change it, it comes from a server like that